# Setup Project for a Web Application

Tags: .net, web-applications, web-config, setup-project

I have a Setup Project that is creating an installation for an extension of a Web Access (like outlook web access of tfs web access).

The problem is the installation is replacing the original web.config, instead adding/changing  corresponding attributes or nodes.

Someone knows how I should create this Setup Project?

Sebastian

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using? What version of .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic way of doing this. One solution is to rename the web.config in your setup project to something like "web.config.update".

Create a console application which reads in web.config and web.config.update and merges them to a new web.config. Add this application to the setup project and make it run after the install is complete.

But if you are using VS2010 then @Oded´s solution is a better one. Keep a copy of your environments config files inside the project and have the build task transform them for you.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant with: "Keep a copy of your environments config files inside the project and have the build task transform them for you." Can you please explain it detailed?

Comment: Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx and the video link by @Oded. What you do is have web.server1.config, web.server2.config etc in your project, and you add transformations to what is different from the different environments. When create a deployment package for the project you get the correct web.config for your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio 2010 introduced [`web.config` transforms](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/06/16/visual-studio-2010-web-config-transforms.aspx) that help with such deployment problems.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/Video/ff801895) howto video on how it works.

This will still replace the web.config, however, with the values you specify for the environment.

Comment: This will create a separate release/debug version of web.config, but it won´t merge with an existing web.config which is deployed will it? But it´s a better solution as the config files are easily kept in a source repository, and you should not modify web.config on the web server.